# Protractor End-to-end multiCapabilities: Internet Explorer simultaneously

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, protractor, automated-tests

For testing my AngularJS 1.6 app, I've set up Protractor 5 with `multiCapabilities` in its config. The intention is that two instances of the same browser run in parallel, representing two users of the application interacting with each other. I know that's probably not best practice, but the harm has already been done and refactoring is currently out of the question.

That set-up works well in Chrome and Firefox, but Internet Explorer 11 (via remote Selenium 3.11) seems to interpret `multiCapabilities` differently: It won't open two IE instances running in parallel, but rather one after the other.

In the Selenium config, `maxInstances` is set to 4 and `browser.forkNewDriverInstance` works.

So, is there anything I could do to make Internet Explorer run two instances parallel/simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is described in the [Selenium wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#multiple-instances-of-internetexplorerdriver) and worked for me:

- In Selenium config set `"ie.forceCreateProcessApi": true,    "ie.browserCommandLineSwitches": "-private"`
- In Windows Registry set: HKLM_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main path should contain key TabProcGrowth to 0